# Applying a facet query in Solr

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to implement a price range facet query by doing this

```
facet.query=[* TO 8]&facet.query=[8 TO 15]&facet.query=[15 TO *]
```

Firstly, how do I name this query as "PriceRange" (or similar) so that in the results it would look something like

```
<facet_queries>
   <pricerange>
       <int name="[* TO 8]">XX</int>
       <int name="[8 TO 15]">XX</int>
       <int name="[15 TO *]">XX</int>
   </pricerange>
 </facet_queries>
```

And secondly how to apply a query filter for the case when someone actually clicks on say "8 TO 15"?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can rename it in your program or you can use [XsltResponseWriter](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/XsltResponseWriter) to rename it using XSL style sheet.
2. add `&fq=price:[15 TO *]` to your URL, if your field is `price`